# Python program for testing the Collatz Conjecture

Tags: python, performance, formatting, collatz-sequence

This is a simple program to test if integers will follow an interesting, improvable statement that if disproven, calls for a bravo.

But, ignoring the pretentious poetry, this code allows the user to input a number, which, if it is a finite, positive integer, will be calculated according to the Collatz Conjecture as stated/commented out below. Any optimizations? Obvious mistakes? Formatting issues?

Maybe let me know how to inform the user that the function-ception went a few levels too deep?

```
# The Collatz conjecture states that
# when you take a finite, positive integer, and
# if it's even, divide by 2, or
# if it's odd, multiply by 3 and add 1,
# and repeat this process enough times,
# you will eventually end up with one.
# Here's a module to demonstrate it.

def collatz(x):
  if abs(int(x)) == x:
    if x == 1:
      print ("The Collatz Conjecture works with this number!")
      print ("It took %s repetitions to reach 1.") % (collatz.counter)
    elif x % 2 == 0:
      y = x / 2
      print ("%s") % (y)
      collatz.counter += 1
      collatz(y)
    elif x % 2 == 1:
      y = x * 3 + 1
      print ("%s") % (y)
      collatz.counter += 1
      collatz(y)
    else:
      print ("Oh, my god!")
      print ("This number does NOT work with the Collatz Conjecture!")
      print ("You've disproven it!")
      print ("...Or maybe this program is broken. Try viewing the source?")
  else:
    print ("That isn't a finite positive integer...")

collatz.counter = 0

#Here's our attempt:

collatz(int(raw_input("Enter a finite positive integer")))
```

Comment: When you use this function twice the `counter` will have as a value the sum of the steps needed. It is never reset to zero.

Comment: Also this will hit a `RecursionLimit` for some numbers.

Comment: Also, this can never find a value for which the collatz conjecture is wrong. Any number is either even or odd, so the `else` will never be reached.

Comment: @Graipher Yes, I'm aware of the Recursion Limit. It's in the question. Though, is `except RecursionLimit` the valid vocabulary? In that case, that does answer the question, though.

Also, good on you pointing out the `counter` flaw (I'll just reset it after 1 has been reached, I suppose).

Comment: It is a `RuntimeError`. Yeah just add it in the `x == 1` case.

Comment: @Graipher Isn't `RuntimeError` just the general error code? I want to be certain that it only covers `RecursionLimit`. I can say that it's generally a bad idea to output the exact same message for every possible error, especially when it's only intended for a single type. After all, if there's a divide-by-zero error and the program complains `OVERFLOW: That number was too large!`, it'll definitely raise eyebrows.

Comment: The only way to check it is the recursion limit triggering it is to look at the error string.

Answer (score 2):

*"Oh, my god!"* will only be reached if the number is neither odd nor even, which will never be the case for any integer.

For a number that will never reach 1 and thus disprove the conjecture, your program would run forever (yet still never reach *"Oh, my god!"*). Welcome to the halting problem.

But as computer resources are limited, you will run into a stack overflow with the depth of your recursive function calls, whether the number would reach 1 eventually or not. For very large numbers, your program will simply crash, which won't tell you anything about the conjecture.

One way to solve that would be to not use recursion. To do so, return the result `y` from your function instead of calling the function again. Then call your function in a `while` loop that stops at 1, feeding the output of a previous call to your function to the next one.

This is still the halting problem, though. Does the computation just take very long or does it never finish (the latter would disprove the conjecture)? You never know.

To solve that too, you'd have to check if your program is trapped in a cycle of numbers (that does not contain 1)

Comment: That's... a good point. Now the question is how to compare an output to prior ones, as to ensure no number is ever repeated? That's the only single case that would indicate an infinite loop.

Comment: @Papayaman1000 well, this is code review, not code **p**review. You probably have to keep track of the numbers somehow, then check them.

Comment: @I'lladdcommentstomorrow: "which will never be the case for any real number." Sorry to be pedantic 2.5 is never odd nor even, so I think you mean integers. :P

Comment: @Dair yes right, my bad. Answer edited.